# How to cancel request generated by Swagger Codegen

Tags: android, request, swagger, cancellation, codegen

I am generating a lib with Swagger-codegen. The library I used was Volley. It doesn't seem the generated code has any way to cancel a request.

Is there anyway to cancel the request through the generated code?

As our api spec may change between each version, I can not apply big code change to the generated code. Otherwise, it will be difficult to apply same change every time.

Comment: can you elaborate a bit more on "cancelling" a HTTP request? is that another HTTP request sent to the server to undo the previous request?

Comment: Seems like tweaking the templates to add this is what you'll want to do.  I do think that cancelling requests is a good thing, but having better control over request and connect timeouts is probably your issue.